# Using CodeMirror editor in custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development, custom-component, editor

I am trying to use CodeMirror as the editor for a field inside a component I am developing. I have specified the editor as `codemirror` in the form.xml file but I get a javascript error on the page:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined`.

Here is the entry in my form.xml file:

```
    <field name="myfield"
            type="editor"
            label="COM_MYCOMPONENT_MYFIELD_LABEL"
            description="COM_MYCOMPONENT_MYFIELD_DESC"
            default=""
            editor="codemirror|none"
            filter="raw"
            />
```

Comment: I've tested your field definition in a J!3.6.2 and it is working fine. I've even tried to disable the CodeMirror plugin, but the control degrades to a text area and no javascript error. I suggest you look for script conflicts.